# Ruby on Rails and SQLite encrypted database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, sqlcipher

I am using Rails 5.2.2 and SQLCipher Version 3.2.0 (based on SQLite 3.8.6).

I have encrypted the SQLite database using sqlcipher but I am not able to load the rails application. The message is get is as follows:

> SQLite3::NotADatabaseException: file is encrypted or is not a database: SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE name <> 'sqlite_sequence' AND name = 'schema_migrations' AND type IN ('table')

I think that my issue lies in updating the file config/database.yml and specifying the password. I have tried specifying options like password, key, etc. but with no success.

I was wondering whether it is at all possible to use encrypted SQLite database in rails?

Comment: Unless the Ruby sqlite bindings you're using is a version that specifically supports this sqlcipher thing, no, it won't be able to open the database.

Comment: Hi, my ruby version is 2.5.3. How can I check whether this supports sqlcipher?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a matter of which version of Ruby you are using, it's a matter of does there exist an adapter for the database you would like to use.

Rails tries to talk to all databases the same way,  each database technology needs to provide an `adapter` to translate what Rails is asking for into the commands needed by that database technology to accomplish what Rails is asking for.

This configuration is done in the config/database.yml file,  which might look something like the following (notice the adapter stanza):

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

There are many database adapters available,  including SQLite, but I have not seen any for SQLCipher, you might have better luck searching than I did.

From what I have seen most Rails apps don't encrypt the entire database, but do however encrypt certain columns, for example storing some encrypted version of a password or access token.

Comment: Thank you for the great information. This is what I started to suspect and spent whole time yesterday in looking for a suitable database adapter but no luck till now. Yes, column wise encryption is what is done in most cases and some databases do only that. I somehow feel that ability to use encrypted sqlite database is a very powerful usecase, and have noted this issue in my to do list for daily research, as soon as I make a breakthrough will post the updates.